# aspnet with angular 4 template has changed

Tags: asp.net, angular

I opening angular 4 with asp.net core project with this command

```
yo aspnetcore-spa
```

and then I choose angular and I get a new template. I mean I see files I never see before e.g : app.module.clinet.ts , app.module.server.ts

[image]

but before a week I opened project and I don't see that and I want this version (to downgrade because I don't really love the changes)
I want as in the photo
[image]

Comment: The documentation for this is here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/ You may get better results commenting there.

Comment: Yes, I already saw this docs but i looking solution for this issue